# Parse M3U file locations to fully qualified paths

Tags: vb.net, m3u

I would like to parse the file location information in an M3U playlist into fully qualified paths.  The possible formats in M3U files seem to be:

c:\mydir\songs\tune.mp3

\songs\tune.mp3

..\songs\tune.mp3

For the first example, just leave it alone.  For the second add the directory that the playlist resides in so it would become c:\playlists\songs\tune.mp3 and the same for the third case so it would also become: c:\playlists\songs\tune.mp3.

I'm using vb under VS2008 and I can't find a way to recognise each of the potential location formats in the M3U file.  System.IO.Path offers no solution that I can find.  I've searched extensively for terms like "convert relative path to absolute" but no luck.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `..\ ` means go up one directory.  If your M3U is in `C:\Playlists`, then the meaning of `..\songs\tune.mp3` is actually `C:\songs\tune.mp3`

Comment: Thanks for your comment Brad, understood.  Maybe the only answer is to test for ":", "\", "..\" or none of the above at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a batch script that just reads the m3u file line by line, and then just parse each line looking for ":" , and for "..", and edit the string as needed. You can then just write the "converted" strings to another file...